# Can't install xdebug using pecl

Tags: php, linux, xampp, xdebug, pecl

This is what I have done: first of all I installed php5-dev. php.h is in /usr/include/php5/main. After that:

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
./pecl install xdebug
```

Result:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c:25:17: fatal error: php.h: No such file or directory
```

I think I must say to pecl in which include directory it must search... but how?

Comment: I found that xampp for linux uses its own include paths, you must also install the Development package from apachefriends site.

Comment: Isnt xdebug available as a normal package for most distributions? I would suggest this instead of PECL. Easier and doesnt need any make compile or other majix!

Comment: Also, you might want to use your normal apache and PHP if your on Linux. Should be much easier to manage and is closer to real live server environments (but might be matter of taste)

Comment: @ToBe: yes, this is what I've done in the end :)